# How can I clean up Connect to Server's recent servers?

Tags: nautilus

My *Recent Servers* list of Nautilus' `Connect to Server` dialog is cluttered because instead of listing the **recent** connections, it lists **all** the connections I've ever made.

[image: Connect to Server dialog]

It is annoying because every time I try to find an entry I have to scroll through a lot of references to old, already dead, servers. I don't want to bookmark the connection because I have a big bookmark list, which I don't want to clutter, too.

Where on disk is this list stored? Or, how can I clean it up?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Easily you can edit the file:

```
gedit ~/.config/nautilus/servers
```

You can edit the file and remove some entries or if you just want to delete all history you can remove this file:

```
rm ~/.config/nautilus/servers
```

Comment: Now it's time to write a GUI program to parse it and select entries I wish to remove. Thanks.

Comment: @EricCarvalho You are welcome, share it with us buddy

Comment: @EricCarvalho did you write a gui? sure wish it was built-into nautilus!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with nautilus 3.34.1 / ubuntu 19.10. The file doesn't exist anymore. @KingLeoric works though

Answer (score 4):

I was also trying to clear the "recent servers" list on Nautilus.
I use Ubuntu 18. I found the file `servers` at this location:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a confusion with a different problem:  the *Other Locations* list. Happened to me!  Here is the link to deal with the *Other Locations* problem:

[Ubuntu 20.04.1: How to remove Network file sharing location on Nautilus under other locations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284524/ubuntu-20-04-1-how-to-remove-network-file-sharing-location-on-nautilus-under-ot)