# Remove Server Location from Files application in 16.04

Tags: 16.04

In the Files application, in the bottom left panel, there is a "Connect to Server" link listed. I tried putting in some credentials to see if I could map to my Google drive. It didn't work, so now I would like to remove the xxx@gmail.com item clicking that function created.

Comment: You want to remove it from the **Recent Servers** box that is shown when you click **Connect to Server**, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/646387/how-can-i-clean-up-connect-to-servers-recent-servers.

Comment: I guess it's the "Recent Servers" box. There is also "Computer" listed there and an FTP location that is working for me.

Comment: I tried to MV the .config/nautilus/servers to a backup filename, but it didn't seem to have any effect. I'm not even sure this application is Nautilus. When I select help, about, it lists "Files" as the application name.