# How to remove and forget a local ftp network from nautilus?

Tags: networking, nautilus, ftp

I recently added a ftp client folder (*of my android device*) using nautilus, and also saved the user name and password of my ftp server.

Now, I want to remove it, and also forget its password, so everytime it asks for it.
How can it be done?

Comment: There should be an XML file - see [How can I clean up Connect to Server's recent servers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646387/how-can-i-clean-up-connect-to-servers-recent-servers) - the location used to be `~/.config/nautilus/servers` but is now `~/.config/gtk-3.0/servers` afaik

Comment: Sorry, but it still remembers the password! I want to actually forget the network on whole, like android forgets WiFi networks, and prompts for password again.