# Ubuntu 20.04.1: How to remove Network file sharing location on Nautilus under other locations

Tags: server, 20.04, nautilus, smb, nemo

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, GNOME version 3.36.3 and I've mistakenly added two different links to the same server but I haven't been able to remove the other duplicate. Basically I struggled to link my NAS and tried a few recommended commands in terminal and  also tried the Connect to Server entry in the window and one of them worked twice and I can't figure out how to undo them.

Here's the commands that I think got them there:

```
87  sudo apt install nemo
88  nemo smb://remus.local     
90  nemo smb://REMUS.local/home
```

I tried sudo apt remove nemo to no avail, both locations remain.

In the image under Networks, I'm trying to remove one of the two REMUS (File Sharing) locations. One other tidbit of information is that they go away when I turn off my wired connection if that is useful but both show back up once turned on again.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Nautilus view of Other Locations
[image: Nautilus view of Other Locations]

**Update: Oct 17 09:45CST**

I ran `sudo find / -name '*REMUS*'` and `sudo find / -name '*remus*'`
and they gave me the following results:

```
/home/justin/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/smb-server:server=remus.local-d707b075.log
/home/justin/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/smb-server:server=remus.local
/home/justin/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/afp-server:host=REMUS.local
/home/justin/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/afp-server:host=REMUS.local-f6615da2.log
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

I removed those files but it didn't do anything for me. I'm going to start some research on removal of smb and afp servers.

**Update Oct 17 10:34**

I now have removed one of the two network locations but have no idea how.  As stated before I deleted those files but then I removed nfs-common and nemo, ie `sudo apt remove nfs-common` and `sudo apt remove nemo`. Then I logged out and logged back out and one was gone.

From a problem standpoint this is resolved but from a knowledge standpoint it is still very much open. I have no idea what action did it because it didn't change until after I logged out and back in. I'd like for this to remain open if someone has some insight on removal of smb or afp-servers because I'm sure I will deal with again in the future.

Comment: Is there something matching in the file `~/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Unfortunately no. I don't see that file in that directory, only search-metadata. I see the following lines in that file:     [directory]
nautilus-list-view-sort-column=search_relevance
nautilus-list-view-sort-reversed=true

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure I understand the question.

You have two entries under Other Locations because the server is broadcasting it's presence to the network with two different protocols.

One is smb via mDNS ( Avahi in Linux ):

> /home/justin/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/**smb-server:server=remus.local**

And the other one is afp ( apple file protocol ) via mDNS:

> /home/justin/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/**afp-server:host=REMUS.local**

The Linux client can connect using either so you can't remove one of them from the client. You need to go to the server and tell it you only want to share it using one or the other.